# Only 2 clusters are plotted instead of 3 after Linear Discriminant Analysis

Tags: python, python-2.7, matplotlib

I cant put all my data into a graph. This is what I got

[image: click]

This is what I need to get

[image: click]

I'm using this code:

```
import pandas
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from sklearn.discriminant_analysis import LinearDiscriminantAnalysis
import numpy as np

dataset = np.loadtxt("wine.data.csv", delimiter=",")
print(dataset)
X = dataset[:,1:14]
y = dataset[:,0]
target_names = ['class_0', 'class_1', 'class_2']

lda = LinearDiscriminantAnalysis(n_components=2)
X_lda = lda.fit(X,y).transform(X)
plt.figure()
for c, i, target_name in zip("rgb", [0, 1, 2], target_names):
    plt.scatter(X_lda[y == i, 0], X_lda[y == i, 1], c=c, label=target_name)

plt.show()
plt.plot([-6,2],[-6,4],"k-")
plt.plot([5,0],[-6,4],"k-")
plt.legend()
plt.title('LDA of WINE dataset')
plt.show()
```

The dataset is downloaded from here [WINE dataset](https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/wine/wine.data). Also I am using Python 2.7. I am new to this and would appreciate any kind of help.
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the first `plt.show()`

```
# plt.show() # remove this
plt.plot([-6,2],[-6,4],"k-")
plt.plot([5,0],[-6,4],"k-")
plt.legend()
plt.title('LDA of WINE dataset')
plt.show()
```

As soon as you call `plt.show()`, the plot is generated and all your code below this line will be ignored.

Furthermore, change `[0, 1, 2]` to `[1, 2, 3]`:

```
for c, i, target_name in zip("rgb", [1, 2, 3], target_names):
    plt.scatter(X_lda[y == i, 0], X_lda[y == i, 1], c=c, label=target_name)
```

Now you get your desired output.

Comment: But my third cluster is still missing... thats the problem. Thank you for your comment!

Comment: Added the solution.

Comment: Thank you so much!